# YOLOv8 : RuntimeError: An attempt has been made to start a new process before the current process has finished its bootstrapping phase

Tags: python, yolo

An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

```
    This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
    child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom
    in the main module:

        if __name__ == '__main__':
            freeze_support()
            ...

    The "freeze_support()" line can be omitted if the program
    is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.
```

**
This error shows up when trying to train a YOLOv8 model in a python environment**
from ultralytics import YOLO

```
# Load a model
model = YOLO("yolov8n.yaml")  # build a new model from scratch
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)

# Use the model
results = model.train(data="coco128.yaml", epochs=3)  # train the model
results = model.val()  # evaluate model performance on the validation set
results = model("https://ultralytics.com/images/bus.jpg")  # predict on an image
success = YOLO("yolov8n.pt").export(format="onnx")  # export a model to ONNX format
```

Answer (score 17):

I managed to overcome this by keeping the model process code under the name of the top-level environment (if **name** == '**main**':) , as seen below:

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a model
model = YOLO("yolov8n.yaml")  # build a new model from scratch
model = YOLO("yolov8n.pt")  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Use the model
    results = model.train(data="coco128.yaml", epochs=3)  # train the model
    results = model.val()  # evaluate model performance on the validation set
    results = model("https://ultralytics.com/images/bus.jpg")  # predict on an image
    success = YOLO("yolov8n.pt").export(format="onnx")  # export a model to ONNX format
```

Answer (score 0):

In python code, just mentioned `workers=0`. It will be fine.

e.g.

```
from ultralytics import YOLO

# Load a model
model = YOLO('yolov8s-seg.yaml')  # build a new model from YAML
model = YOLO('yolov8s-seg.pt')  # load a pretrained model (recommended for training)
model = YOLO('yolov8s-seg.yaml').load('yolov8n.pt')  # build from YAML and transfer weights

# Train the model
results = model.train(data='./data/dataset.yaml', epochs=100, imgsz=640, workers=0)
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same error, instead of using the python script I just used the CLI to do the training.

from the ultralytics directory go to the terminal:

```bash
yolo task=detect mode=train epochs=100 data=yolov8n.yaml model=yolov8n.pt imgsz=640
```